# extracting file in the format of .h5.gz

Tags: python, linux, extract, linux-mint, file-extension

I am facing issue while extrating GPM DPR Data downloaded from Jaxa tropical cyclone data archeive the format of the file downloaded is .h5.gz . I know how to extract .gz but in this case it is not extracting . Please help . I am attaching a copy of this file you people can solve it ...

Thank you

The given link will trasfer you to the file
https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230227JIaIrrYQ

I tried using python gunzip as well as native Linux mint extractor

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a gz file but an HDF file.

Comment: You can determine the real type of a file (for most types) with the command   file:  file filename.   This will determine the type regardless of name and ending.